# what is difference between Rudra Avatar and normal Avatar of Shiva? is Veerbhadra just Avatar or Rudra Avatar?

Tags: shiva, rudra

Shiva has 11 Rudra Avatar but these name doesn't include Hanuman as well as Veerbhadra. I have seen an answer regarding Hanumaan but have curiosity about Veerbhadra , he is for sure avatar but is he a Rudra? what is the difference between a normal Avatar and Rudra Avatar, they all are form of Shiva only, they why there is a category of Rudra Avatar?